# Storing Bitmap to jpg in Android using WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-storage

I am looking forward for an Android application Paint , which displays an preview of image . I want to store that drawn image in JPEG or PNG format into my external or internal storage of my device.
please help me with this 
Following is code for MainActitvity.java file:

```
package ai.fritz.tflitedemo;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import ai.fritz.tflitedemo.ml.DigitsDetector;
import ai.fritz.tflitedemo.ui.PaintView;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private static final int PIXEL_WIDTH = 28;
private DigitsDetector mnistClassifier;

@BindView(R.id.button_detect)
View detectButton;

@BindView(R.id.button_clear)
View clearButton;

@BindView(R.id.text_result)
TextView mResultText;

@BindView(R.id.paintView)
PaintView paintView;

@BindView(R.id.preview_image)
ImageView previewImage;

@BindView(R.id.inference_preview)
LinearLayout inferencePreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[] 
  {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    mnistClassifier = new DigitsDetector(this);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);

    detectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onDetectClicked();
        }
    });

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClearClicked();
        }
    });
}


private void onDetectClicked() {
    inferencePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(paintView.getBitmap(), PIXEL_WIDTH, PIXEL_WIDTH, false);
    int digit = mnistClassifier.classify(scaledBitmap);
    previewImage.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

    SaveImage(scaledBitmap);
    if (digit >= 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Found Digit = " + digit);
        mResultText.setText(getString(R.string.found_digits, String.valueOf(digit)));
    } else {
        mResultText.setText(getString(R.string.not_detected));
    }
}
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log");
    File myDir = new File(root+"/saved_images");
    Log.d("root",myDir.toString());
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ())
        file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void onClearClicked() {
    mResultText.setText("");
    paintView.clear();
}
 }
```

Here is the code for permission access:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It throws error stating cannot find the source of the file

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/saved_images/Image- 
6131.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

. But the preview works fine.

I want to store the drawn image as jpg file .

Thanks in advance

Comment: show which error exactly you get, and also it's stacktrace

Comment: It does not create the folder into my storage and throws following error line in my trace:   ` 

      "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/saved_images/Image- 
      6131.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Comment: Note: For Android 8+ you need both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: have you requested runtime permissions?

Comment: @ChristosThemelis Thanks it worked for external storage. How do i do it for internal storage ? Can you help me out

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I get dialogue box asking for permission for accessing my storage one time permission as soon as i install the APK.

Comment: That is not what I mean. The Runtime Permissions.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko No i guess . i am new to this .

Comment: search for the Runtime permissions and how to request those. They have been introduced in Android 6.0. It was introduced in October 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android 8+ you need both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Ask permissions:

```
private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 1111;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  if ((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_STORAGE);
  }
}
```

And here you will get the result:

```
@TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.permission_ok), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    recreate();                 
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
                    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.assign_permissions));
                    builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.permissions_denied));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            finish();
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```